# How to add input values using array_sum, when my input data came from a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, html, mysqli

I am doing a quiz generator with different question categories (Category: English, Math, Programming etc.), and I have to set the number of items for each category.

I used this block of codes to retrieve data from tbl_category:

**SetItemLimit.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","learning_assessment") or die("Cannot connect to database!");
$sql="select * from tbl_category;";
$rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form action="SetItemLimit.php" method="post">

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Number of Items</th>
</tr>
<?php do{?>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['category'];?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="perCatLimit" /></td>
</tr>
<?php }while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs));?>

</table>


TOTAL NUMBER OF THE TEST ITEMS: <input type="text" name="numQ"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="SetItemLimit" value="SET ITEM LIMIT" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I wanted to happen is, when I set the number of items for each category and clicked submit button(SetItemLimit)-- the values will be added up and display to textbox(numQ).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SetItemLimit'])){

}
```

can I use

```
 array_sum()
```

?

Comment: They are evaluating at the time of the `do {} while()` loop correct? The only reason I ask is because I don't use this method so I just need clarification based on the PHP manual.

Comment: They would be evaluated separately from the loop, Sir. They would be evaluated when submit button is clicked and not at the time of the loop. But, any method and advice would  be very helpful, Sir.  @Rasclatt.

Comment: Are the values coming from the `perCatLimit` fields? And presumably you would have a bunch of `perCatLimit` fields?

Comment: YES SIR. perCatLimit are my input fields which values are to be added. @Rasclatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make the `perCatLimit` be an array input so `perCatLimit[]`. See below:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['perCatLimit'])){
            $setLimit = array_sum($_POST['perCatLimit']);
        }

    $con    =   mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","learning_assessment") or die("Cannot connect to database!");
    $sql    =   "select * from tbl_category;";
    $rs     =   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $rows   =   mysqli_fetch_array($rs); ?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="SetItemLimit.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Number of Items</th>
        </tr>
        <?php do{?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['category'];?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="perCatLimit[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($rs));?>
    </table>
    TOTAL NUMBER OF THE TEST ITEMS:
    <input type="text" <?php echo (isset($setLimit) && is_numeric($setLimit))? 'value="'.$setLimit.'"':''; ?> name="numQ"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="SetItemLimit" value="SET ITEM LIMIT" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on my code. I wrote `SetItemLimit[]` but meant to write `perCatLimit[]` in the description and `isset` portion. Sorry sorry, that will cause it to not work...

Comment: Sir, on my browser says: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, sting given \SetItemLimit.php on line 3.

Comment: Did you modify this line of code: `<td><input type="text" name="perCatLimit[]" /></td>`?